# Where do I use Composer for PHP?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm still new to coding and I'm learning everything on my own. This is a silly question for you but after reading a dozen of articles I am still confused.

I have a php based website on a shared host. After reading the various articles on  benefits of using repositories and Composer, I decided to give it a try. These are my difficulties so far:

Which version of the operating system of Composer should I download, to enable me to install/update repositories of my cPanel based shared hosting?

If I am to install Windows version, how do I connect to my shared hosting to install/update the repositories?

My apologies for my silly questions, but it would really help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think any of that makes sense.

Comment: @JonStirling I'm still new to coding, that's why I'm confused

Comment: Composer is pure php program contained in phar archive. It is executed directly from terminal, usually via ssh connection by running it like usual php file. SO there is no OS dependency for composer, only for php installation, and I doubt you could run it from cPanel unless you hosting provider is supporting it explicitly.

Comment: Your question is actually worded in a useful generic way, and it comes up a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using shared hosting, you are unlikely to be able to use Composer on the host itself. Furthermore, you are not encouraged to use Composer "on production".

I would recommend you use Composer locally (on the O/S of your local machine), to compose your project and install your dependent packages. Once it's all working and tested with your own code, you upload your entire development directory tree including the resulting vendor library - as one big FTP/SCP upload of "flat files".

Once you get more advanced you could adventure into automated deployment techniques, but I feel for now you would be best to stick to using Composer as a local development tool to manage your codebase.

Update, further details:

Composer is really a tool to help you manage your codebase in development. It's not intended as a "deployment" tool. Previously you used to find a library you liked, download it, unzip it into your codebase somewhere random like "lib/stuff" and then link to it, and commit it into your version control system (VCS). OK, but they a year later you want to update it and you have to download it again, figure out where you saved it and how to overwrite the files, or delete old ones... it gets hard. Also your VCS repository gets full of 3rd-party components - even duplicates of the same one! Composer solved this by bringing order to this long-term dependency management chaos.

The reason you don't want to run Composer "on production" (i.e. your live website), is that during the process of download, update, composition your website will probably be broken. Even if the composer process works, this could be several minutes of broken site. After the update has finished - you now have a completely new set of 3rd party packages: how do you know they are compatible with your codebase?

So therefore you only do composer updates locally, test everything, amend your code to work the shiny new updates, and only then do you decide to upload the whole new site to the server - just as if you'd cobbled it all together manually. The deployment is independent.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Comment: You're welcome, I've added more detail on the "not encouraged" statement, and what composer is meant to solve.